# How to turn on ZSL (zero shutter lag) in Android Camera 1?

Tags: android, android-camera

Is there way of enabling ZSL on old Camera API? Nothing in official documentation, maybe in `Parameters`, maybe it is manufacturer dependent value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a device-specific setting. If it is supported, you can use the string-based [set()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters) API to control it. You can find the device-specific parameter name and often the expected parameter values from flatten() result.

It is important to remember that setParameters() call is slow and may produce a RuntimeException for any one of hundreds of plausible or unexpected reasons, so you should always wrap it in try…catch.

Comment: Hi @alex-cohn , do you know how to find this "string-based" key? Where to look for it? Ask manufacturer?

Comment: You can learn a lot by looking at the flattened parameters. If the manufacturer is ready to cooperate, definitely this is the best.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't found this method flatten: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#flatten()